# How to enable users to edit ordering in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

Here's the scenario: I have a Song Entity and a PlayList entity and they have many to many relationship. I need that a user can order the songs related to each playlist so that s/he can listen to songs in that order. I'm not sure what's the best way to implement this.

I'd love to hear you guys' ideas and suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this case before. Cord data does not store the records in any particular order.

You need to introduce a **new attribute** for the ordering. In your data model this would be an `Integer`, in your model class an `NSNumber`. Of course, when the user edits the table, you need to reflect the change of song order in your date model as well and save when appropriate. (In a `UITableView`, I usually do that in `commitEditingStyle:`).

Comment: Hi Mundi, thanks for the answer. I actually thought about this but since there's a many to many relationship, wouldn't the ordering of songs in one playlist affect the ordering in another one as a song can be in different playlists?

Comment: You are right! Perhaps you need a new entity, e.g. `Entry` that has a many-to-one relationship to `Playlist`, a many-to-one relationship to `Song` and an `integer` attribute. (You would not need your old many-to-many relationships any more.)

Comment: Yeah that would have worked. But I didn't want to change relationships as I've already written a good portion of code considering it. I went through a new entity with 3 attributes : object_id for song, object_id for playlist and ordering and it works too.